# zsh: command not found: pod. Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, terminal

I'm trying to connect Firebase authentication for my login/signup page, but when I try to connect it in terminal "zsh: command not found: pod" comes up. I have installed cocoapods and then tried again. I've tried using an administrator account. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you check that the pod installation is in your Path variable? You can try `echo $PATH`. If not, you should try restarting your shell

Comment: Yes, seems pretty straightforward. Say `which pod`. If nothing comes up, you don't have `pod` in your path. Typically this would be because of a failure to take control of your ruby; if you are using the system ruby, you need to stop doing that immediately.